# What exactly is content-aware?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So there are tools in photoshop like "content-aware fill" and "content-aware scale". I also see a content aware check mark in photoshop a lot of times, like when I use the crop tool

[image]

and when I use the patch tool, I "content-aware" selected on the dropdown-

[image]

So, my question is, what exactly **IS** "content-aware"? Is it a tool, or collective name for multiple tools? Is it a setting, or something you chose from a dropdown? What is the meaning of the **term** "content-aware" ?

And what is the exact function of "content-aware" ?

Answer (score 5):

Content-Aware is a technology that enhances the capabilities of multiple tools within Photoshop that assists in patching, (re)moving, scaling, filling, and extending pixels in rasterized images. It shows up in various tools throughout Photoshop but the technology behaves according to which tool it's being applied with.

The most basic explanation: when activated, it recognizes the content in your image to determine how to best make up the differences made in editing processes.

For example, when applied to the Patch Tool:

> The Patch tool is used to remove unwanted image elements. The
>   **Content-Aware** option in the Patch tool **synthesizes nearby content for
>   seamless blending with the surrounding content.**
>
> *[-Adobe Support:Content-Aware Patch and Move](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/content-aware-patch-move.html)*

And in regards to the Move Tool:

> Use the Content-Aware Move tool to select and move a part of a
>   picture. **The image is recomposed, and the hole left behind is filled
>   using matching elements from the picture.** You do not need to carry out
>   intensive edits involving layers and complex selections.
>
> You can use the Content-Aware Move tool in two modes:
>
> - Use the Move mode to place objects in different locations (most
>     effectively when the background remains similar).
> - Use the Extend mode
>     to expand or contract objects such as hair, trees, or buildings. To
>     best extend architectural objects, use photos shot on a parallel
>     plane, rather than at an angle.
>
> *[-Adobe Support:Content-Aware Patch and Move](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/content-aware-patch-move.html)*

These are just a couple of examples of how the Content-Aware technology is applied to different tools within Photoshop. As you can see, it's a powerful editing enhancement that uses the pixel information from the rasterized image to best guess how to fill in the "holes" that result from various editing operations. For a more in depth look at all of the Content-Aware applications, [Adobe Support has them here.](https://helpx.adobe.com/search.html#q=Conent-Aware&t=All&sort=relevancy&CommonProduct=Photoshop)

Comment: what does restarize mean?

Comment: oh i just checked the definition of restarize, it says "convert (an image stored as an outline) into pixels that can be displayed on a screen or printed.", but isn't every image made out of pixels?

Comment: also, so when we use "content-aware" to move objects, its really just the patch tool without us telling it where to blend in from. And when we use the patch tool to tell phootshop from where to use pixels to blend in the  space left by the removed object, it also uses some content-aware to do the blending thing. And when we use spot healing, that also uses content aware, right?

Comment: That sounds about right. Keep in mind that it's not always a super accurate technology so you may still have to do some editing after the fact. The Content-Aware does a lot of the "heavy lifting" though.

Comment: In regards to your question about raster images, I'm speaking primarily on rasterized vs. vector, in which [Vector images are made of hundreds of thousands of tiny lines and curves (or paths) to create an image. Raster images are composed of pixels.](https://designshack.net/articles/layouts/vector-vs-raster-what-do-i-use/)

Answer (score 1):

To get a deeper understanding of what context aware scaling is and how it's actually working I can strongly recommend watching the original video presentation of the technique from 2007 by its inventors Shai Avidan and Ariel Shamir.

Their 5 minute [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NcIJXTlugc) has a technical focus but still manages to explain the concept in a very approachable way. Basically context aware scaling is all about finding vertical and horizontal "paths" of pixels that can safely be removed or expanded without distorting the important parts of the image.

Comment: The "real" answer I was looking for! You can also read the research paper the technique was detailed in from SIGGRAPH 2007: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1275808.1276390